# Microphone mute notification

Tags: shortcut-keys, notification, microphone

I am using the following command within a custom keyboard shortcut to mute my microphone...

```
amixer set Capture toggle
```

My problem is that I have no way of knowing if I am turning the microphone on or off unless I open my sound settings and click the input tab. This makes the shortcut a bit useless. I would like to have an indicator show the current state of the microphone the same way volume status is shown when using a shortcut volume mute key....

[volume mute indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgG2o.png)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu 18.04

In terminal works:

```
amixer set Capture toggle && amixer get Capture | grep '\[off\]' && notify-send "MIC switched OFF" || notify-send "MIC switched ON"
```

But if I just put this command in "Command" field for Custom Shortcut, it doesn't work

I created a Shell Script with path /home/username/ToggleMic.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

amixer set Capture toggle && amixer get Capture | grep "\[off\]" && notify-send "MIC switched OFF" || notify-send "MIC switched ON"
```

And in "Command" field for Custom Shortcut I put:

```
/home/username/ToggleMic.sh
```

And now it works! I can toggle my mic using keyboard shortcut and can see notifications on top of the screen

Comment: Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu! May I suggest you to add some comments on what your code does and why you think it answers the question? Otherwise it will remain cryptic to many readers.

Answer (score 0):

yes there are an extension use it from here
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1113/nothing-to-say/